# AngularJS components $onChanges is getting fired only when assign new val, rather than make a change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, components, onchange

I have this:

```
// child component
this.$onChanges = () => {
  console.log(this.test);
}

// parent component 
$scope.test = {
  team: "barcelona"
};

// parent component html
<my-component test="test"></my-component>

// parent component
$timeout(() => {
  $scope.test.team = "Real madrid"; // NOT fire the $onChanges!
  $scope.test = {
    team: "Real madrid";
  } // DOES fire the $onChanges!
}, 2000);
```

As you can see, components $onChanges function is fired only when assigning value, rather than just updating.

What to do with this?

Comment: On your timeout block you are first updating the team varibale on your test object.
Which just updates the value and does not fire any trigger placed on scope.
But when you call this creates a new object so change event fires. 
You should put you change event on onject level to watch the changes on objects, not on the scope level

Comment: Can you answer it with a code please, since I didn't understand you. `onject level to watch` what that means?

Comment: `this.test.$onChanges = () => {}` need to change event on object level not on the scope level (as @UtkuApaydin said)

Comment: @Jean-PhilippeBergeron ty :)

Comment: Each attribute I should wrap with this.MYATTR.$onChanges ?